# How to declare a different variable for every value in a collection in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to loop through a list and declare integer variables for every value in List.

Example :

```
List<string> VariableNames= new List<string>()
{
    "length",
    "breadth",
    "height"
};
```

OutPut :

```
int length;
int breadth;
int height;
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: Why do you want to do it?

Comment: I want to tie the variable name and variable type together. Want to check if any keyname matching "length" is of type int .

Answer (score 2):

Eric J. has given a good answer but if you still want the list, you can do this:

```
List<string> variableNames = new List<string>()
{
    "length",
    "breadth",
    "height"
};
Dictionary<string,int> names = variableNames.ToDictionary(name => name, integer => 0);
```

But here you aren't generating variables, every `variableName`(key) is given an integer value which is initialized with a value of 0 and you can access that value with something like :

```
names["height"] //returns the integer variable associated with that string.
```

Comment: What if I want to assign different types (not only integer) to the values in my list ? eg., String length ="", int breadth = 100;

Comment: simple change for different type:

    Dictionary<string,float> names = variableNames.ToDictionary(x => x, x => 1.5f);

    Dictionary<string,char> names = variableNames.ToDictionary(x => x, x => 'C');

Comment: @user3370079 you mean like `length` have string type and `breadth` have int type? Try using `object` as @ipavlu has shown. Then cast back to the type you want

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this without code generation.  However, you may be able to solve your problem by using a dictionary instead.

```
Dictionary<string, int> names = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    { "length", 0 },
    { "breadth", 0 },
    { "height", 0 },
};
```

You can then do something like

```
names["length"] = 42;
```